# Is it possible to change the font color and font weight in HTML

Tags: html

So I am doing an assignment and I ran into a problem. I am supposed to change the paragraph font to dark orange and the font weight to 900. Keep in mind this is supposed to be done in HTML, not css. Is this even possible because It only lets me make the font orange not dark orange, and it doesn't let me change the weight.

My code:

```
<p style="color: dark orange" "font-weight: 900">Hello my name is Charles.</p>
```

Comment: That is still CSS, it's just embedded inside HTML

Comment: When you use the style attribute, you're actually using CSS.

Comment: There's no way to do that without CSS. What you're trying to show is still CSS, even if it's inline.

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this question?  Just because it's a beginner question doesn't make it a bad question.  The error isn't a simple typographical error, it's a true error in understanding CSS.  This is probably the best written beginner questions I've read in a long time.

Comment: The value of this question is equal to the value of more complicated questions. This is a duplicate of other questions, of *that* I am certain.

Comment: Crap, I flagged it as a duplicate of the wrong question. Problem with searching for this question is that the questions listed are the *newest ones first.*

Comment: So CSS can still be show inside of HTML without actually writing in the code in the actual css file?

Comment: @phillipswag You can add CSS in three ways: inline, internal, external. Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) You are using inline method now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```html
<p style="color: darkorange;font-weight: 900;">Hello my name is Charles.</p>
```

1. No spaces allowed in color attribute
2. Styles should be added with `;` separation

---

**Update 1**: *From the question comments*

You are using CSS as *inline style*. There are three ways to insert CSS, Inline, Internal, External. [This](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) article helps!

Comment: Up voted. Prior art: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_span

Answer (score 2):

```html
<p style="color: DarkOrange; font-weight: 900">Hello my name is Charles.</p>
```

Of course, if you want a very specific color, you can use Hex codes

```html
<p style="color: #d1a00e; font-weight: 900">Hello my name is Charles.</p>
```